Injecting PVA or a resin to fill deep narrow gaps
Some context. I built a swing set using pre fabricated corner brackets. Because the timber was slightly oversized, I had to plane down the ends to get them to fit. Because I'm no joiner, one of the beams is slightly off, so if you see on the illustration there is a bit of rotation.
As this is the top beam, it causes a tiny bit of further rotation within the bracket if the swing is heavily used, despite being bolted in.
I was wondering if it would be a good idea to, say, syringe inject PVA or a resin all the way in to effectively shim out and fill the gap.
Gap is probably 1-2mm at places where it exists.
Attached a sketch of the cross section. Depth is approx 200mm


If it makes you feel better, hammer a wooden shim or galvanized washer into the gap.
But really, 1-2mm is pretty trivial and I think most people would ignore it.

PVA would not be a good choice as it shrinks so it won't reallly fill the gap, and it's not water resistant for things out in the weather like a swingset.
An epoxy product would be more appropriate, being both non-shrinking and waterproof.

I feel like epoxy may get beaten up still.  The shims suggested by AD should be resistant to that.

How? It completely fills the gap, so there's no room for the bracket to move and beat on it. Unlike a washer jammed in that concentrates the load and crushes the wood, it spreads the load across the full area. The marine epoxy I use is good to about 11,000PSI, even generic hardware-store junk is typically good to 2000PSI.
